# Problem in creating different types of columns in a Winforms gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable

My **windows form** application has a grid view control with filename as a default column. User should create a column of following types

> Text, Number, Currency, 
> Combo Box,
>   Check Box, Radio Button ,
> Date time
>   type (should display DateTimePicker
>   control) and Hyper Link type.

After that i want to pass all rows to next screen for further processing. We can create a column of these types in a grid view but how can i store it in a data table so that i can pass it to next screen.

Or should i create a column in a data table and then assign data table to grid view by 
`gridview.DataSource = dt;` but can we create a these types of columns in a data table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quietly understand what's the problem is?

You need to create clumns in a grid and corresponding columns in a dataTable.

I use `dataTableInstance.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(DataType));` for data tables and for grid i use

```
SomeFieldType field = new SomeFieldType();
field.DataField = "ColumnName"; // Same as above, in dataTableInstance
gridInstance.Columns.Add(field);
```

When data binding should be done: `gridInstance.DataSource = dataTableInstance;`